# PHP - More efficient method for sorting alphanumeric keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**NOTE: I edited the example and replaced all values with 1. The values do not matter, only the keys do. The previous values I had written led to a misunderstanding. Sorry.**

**NOTE: a/b blocks are always continuous. I'm adding this because it wasn't clear. If there is 3a/3b and 5a/5b there will always be 4a/4b and not only 4.**

I have arrays that contain numbered keys with leading zeros. Sometimes, these numbered keys have two variations that I distinguish by using the suffixes a and b. The number of keys with or without variations is unknown, however there is never more than 2 digits; i.e. the highest numerical key is '09'.

The problem is that these array keys need to be sorted numerically, but when suffixes are present, those should take precedence. Using ksort() alone does not achieve this.

For example, ksort() gives me this:

```
$arr = array(
    '01' => 1,
    '02' => 1,
    '03a' => 1,
    '03b' => 1,
    '04a' => 1,
    '04b' => 1,
    '05a' => 1,
    '05b' => 1,
    '06' => 1,
);
```

But, I need this:

```
$arr = array(
    '01' => 1,
    '02' => 1,
    '03a' => 1,
    '04a' => 1,
    '05a' => 1,
    '03b' => 1,
    '04b' => 1,
    '05b' => 1,
    '06' => 1,
);
```

---

I use some fancy coding gymnastics to get what I want, but it isn't pretty. I'm wondering if there's a better, cleaner way?

---

Here is what I do.

1) I use ksort() which gives me the first of the two arrays above. (The one which isn't yet what I want.)

2) I create two arrays. One for the 'a' suffixes, the other for the 'b' suffixes.

```
$arr_a = array();
$arr_b = array();

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (substr($k, 2) == 'a') {
        $arr_a[$k] = $v;
    } else if (substr($k, 2) == 'b') {
        $arr_b[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

3) I merge the two suffix arrays.

```
$arr_suffixes = array_merge($arr_a, $arr_b);
```

4) I slice up my original array so that I get the part before the suffixes, and the part after the suffixes.

```
$i = array_search(key($arr_suffixes), array_keys($arr));
$length = count($arr_suffixes);

$arr_before_suffixes = array_slice($arr, 0, $i);
$arr_after_suffixes = array_slice($arr, $i + $length);
```

5) Using array_merge, I recombine the sliced arrays to create the array I need.

```
$arr = array_merge($arr_before_suffixes, $arr_suffixes);
$arr = array_merge($arr, $arr_after_suffixes);
```

Finally, we have the correct $arr. Isn't there a better way to do this? It feels really ugly.

Comment: It would not happen. You would either have the '04' key, or both '04a' and '04b'. Note: The values don't matter. They have thrown off some answers below. Only the keys matter.

Comment: I do not got it. 02 < 05a < 03b , but 03b < 06. What is the rule?

Comment: imagine, sorting with numbers, but if number also has anding letter `a` or `b` than sort by something like this `0a4,0a5,0b4,0b5`

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili , but empty space more or less than letter a or b?

Comment: @derp - a/b blocks are always continuous. I should have mentioned this. So, if 3a/3b and 5a/5b there will always be 4a/4b and not only 4.

Comment: I have a similar sort, where I use uksort and within the callback I split the keys using sscanf to do the check

Comment: @Mark Baker - Thanks. Ya, looks like uksort is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You have no formalized rule. I'll try to guess.

```
$arr = array(
    '01' => 1,
    '02' => 1,
    '03a' => 1,
    '03b' => 1,
    '04a' => 1,
    '04b' => 1,
    '05a' => 1,
    '05b' => 1,
    '06' => 1,
);

uksort($arr, function($item1, $item2)
    {
    $last1 = substr($item1, -1);
    $last2 = substr($item2, -1);
    // one of the items is a number or last letters matches
    if (is_numeric($last1) || is_numeric($last2) || $last1 == $last2) 
        // simple number comparison
        return $item1 - $item2;
    else
        // natural order comparison
        return $last1 > $last2 ? 1 : -1;
    });

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: I have no formalized rule? I do, I explain above in detail! Thanks, your example works. This helps a lot.

Comment: Yes! I was just thinking of transmuting your usort to uksort. This is wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function will helps you:

```
$arr = array(
    '01' => 1,
    '02' => 1,
    '03a' => 1,
    '03b' => 1,
    '04a' => 1,
    '04b' => 1,
    '05a' => 1,
    '05b' => 1,
    '06' => 1,
);
$keys = array_keys($arr);
natsort($keys);
$result = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
}
print_r($result); // Your expected result
```

Comment: This is wrong. You get the expected result by 'accident', because of the actual values, not the keys.

Comment: Yes, I should not have given values like that. Perhaps I should change my example? The values can be anything.

Comment: @derp - Edited. That taught me a good lesson in being precise.

Comment: @plutov.by Yes, as derp states, in the example you give the array is not changed at all.

Comment: I had a very irregular key, that would not get sorted by any other means than this. Tried all other solutions. Thanks @plutov.by!

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(
    '01' => 1,
    '02' => 2,
    '03a' => 3,
    '03b' => 6,
    '04a' => 4,
    '04b' => 7,
    '05a' => 5,
    '05b' => 8,
    '06' => 9,
);

uksort(
    $arr,
    function($a, $b) {
        sscanf($a, '%d%s', $an, $as);
        sscanf($b, '%d%s', $bn, $bs);
        if ($as === null || $bs === null || $as === $bs) {
            return $an - $bn;
        }
        return strcmp($as, $bs);
    }
);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Looks more clean than mine.

Comment: @sectus - It's still not going to be very efficient, having to do the callback for every comparison of the quicksort; but it really isn't very different from yours... using sscanf in place of substr, and strcmp rather than your ternary

Comment: Do you think the method in my OP is more efficient?

Comment: Thanks for this variation, it's nice to see different ideas. It really helps.

Comment: @Pierre - It would probably depend on your data volumes, using uksort will be pretty efficient working with small data volumes.... but an array_multisort might be better when working with larger data volumes